# bundle.js not found on javascript MVC project

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, bundle

In local dev enviroment it works fine but when the project is AWS EC2 instance or Google Cloud Plataform instance, bundle.js is not found on browser. Some help, please?

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "agenda",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --ignore public --ignore frontend",
    "dev": "webpack -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.12",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require('path'); // CommonJS

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './frontend/main.js',
  output: {
    publicPath: "/public/",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'assets', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/env']
        }
      }
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

***package.json***

```
  {
  "name": "agenda",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js --ignore public --ignore frontend",
    "dev": "webpack -w"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "csurf": "^1.11.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.12",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

***footer.ejs***

```
<div class="col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
</section>

<script src="/assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

folder structure is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoROP.png)

github project folder: https://github.com/rimancete/js_Avancado/tree/master/node/agenda

app url:
http://agenda.lojardente.com/

Comment: Publishing a node app usually means the host will run `npm start`; all that does is run the express server (using nodemon, which isn't suitable for production). You probably need `"start": "webpack && node server.js"` in your package.json

Comment: @ChrisG shown a new error for me when I did your suggestion lol...
[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
I think my app has a wrong path in somewhere that I can't find one :(

Comment: Does the website work otherwise? Anyway, have you googled the error? It's pretty common when people use XMLHttpRequest and set the async param to false because they want to write "sync" code, but it freezes the browser during the request and creates the above error., I've looked at your frontend code but haven't found any AJAX requests.

Comment: Before my post here I googled for sure. I receive "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED bundle.js:1" error. I'll put the app url on post if this help

Comment: I have no idea how to solve it :( . Has someone any ideas?